# Infragistics UltraTree with checkboxes in selected cells

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview, infragistics

I use the **Infragistics UltraTree control** in a Winforms application as a treelist (**outlook mode**). The problem with the outlook mode is, that it is not possible to have node checkboxes. So my **workaround** is, to use a own **column for the checkboxes**.

My question is now, how can I achive, that there are only **checkboxes in specific cells** (for example only in cells, which belongs to tree level 2)?

At http://news.infragistics.com/forums/p/11661/44028.aspx#44028 there is a solution with ultraCheckEditor, but first, the EditorControl is a "obsolete"-control and I don't know how to include ultraCheckEditor!?!? Although I have `using Infragistics.Win.UltraWinEditors` the class is still not available!?!?

Comment: Belongs on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution in the knowledge base ?
http://devcenter.infragistics.com/Support/KnowledgeBaseArticle.aspx?ArticleID=10092